# NativeScript+Angular UnitTesting

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am new to Native Script with Angular. I need help for writing Unit Tests for Angular components by mocking a service with Karma and Jasmine.

I have followed the Native Script Unit Testing docs (https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/testing) to integrate the Unit Test environment but not much details available how to write test.

Please suggest me how to write or give some repo links of NS + ng Unit Testing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The examples from [nativescript-angular](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/tree/master/tests/app/tests) repo might help you write your unit test cases.